# SSL installation in AWS EC2 redhat linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, redhat

I have purchased  .crt certificate file from ssls.com for enabling SSL and  I tried some method to configuring it in AWS ec2.
Like i added this code in httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
# If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
# the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
# to <VirtualHost *:443>
# Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
# supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
# !important below!
NameVirtualHost *:443 
Listen 443
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mydomain.com/
#other configurations
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/mydomain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/localhost.key
```

After that if i run this code  its giving error.
please help me. do i need to do any other thing.

Comment: i am getting Error Like this " _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence " -@mbaird.

Comment: Maybe, you should do "apache2ctl configtest" to get a brief idea about the error.